# Why is 'would' used here instead of 'will'

Tags: modal-verbs, modality, will-would

Someone commented following line.

"This time,a vote for Democrats(or any party) **would** be a vote for progress;a vote for third front **would** be a vote for instability and indecision."

I don't think that there is need of '**would**' here.Election is going to happen.Nothing is hypothetical.Then why is '**will**' not used here?

Comment: The election *will* happen, but whether one *would* vote for progress or one *would* vote for instability and indecision _are_ hypothetical.

Comment: @AliBeadle then why do we say that "time will tell" instead of "time would tell", for time donot tells.

Comment: 'Time will tell' is not intended literally but means 'the answer/solution will be known in time'. It is certain, not hypothetical, so in most circumstances *will* is more appropriate than *would*.

Answer (score 1):

In modern American English you would probably find many people using *will* rather than *would* here, correct or not.

The subjunctive seems appropriate because, while the election will happen for certain, the actual disposition of the listener's vote is clearly uncertain given that the speaker is describing options the listener might choose.

Consider that the listener cannot (per default assumptions of typical, non-criminal behavior in voting) vote for more than one candidate for a single position in an election. The speaker is, then, describing the effects of votes the listener might *possibly* make, with the actual choices represented by the votes themselves not having any grounding in known fact at the time the statement is made.